# Magento 2.3.4 Product List Grid not rendering HTML Character Entities of Product Name

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

In Magento 2.3.4 Product List Grid,Product Name with  HTML Character Entities not showing properly . HTML Character Entities rendered as  its character reference.